# preg_match_all all combinations with word bounderies

Tags: php, regex

i've got the following string:

```
$string = "König Friedrich August III. von Sachsen - Adel Sachsen, Waidmannsheil, Kapitaler 16ender erlegt auf der Jagd am 2. Oktober 1905, gelaufen 30.06.1909, Verlag, Karlowa Walter, Dresden";
```

Now I wan't to find words in that string using preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all("/\b(abituria)\b|\b(absolvia)\b|\b(adel sachsen)\b|\b(adel)\b|\b(sachsen)\b|\b(könig)\b/i",$string,$matches);
```

The string matches only for

```
array(
  0 => "König",
  1 => "Adel Sachsen"
)
```

but I need that it also returns "Adel" in the $matches-Array.

How can I do that? I think my problem is that: "After the first match is found, the subsequent searches are continued on from end of the last match."

**Update**

That does not work:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=\b(adel sachsen|adel)\b)/ui', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => Adel Sachsen
)


preg_match_all('/(?=\b(adel|adel sachsen)\b)/ui', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);

Array
(
    [0] => Adel
)
```

But i need the following as result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Adel Sachsen,
    [1] => Adel
)
```

Comment: if a particular part of regex pattern matches a text then another pattern won't try to match again the same text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would just search for each word/combination (generate a pattern for each) and [map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) the according match to the result array or set false, if it doesn't match. Then [filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) the false elements:

```
$arr = ["nadel", "adel", "knödel", "sachsen", "adel sachsen"];

$str = "Friedrich August III. von Sachsen - Adel Sachsen";

$res = array_filter(array_map(function ($s) use (&$str) {
       $s = '/\b'.preg_quote($s,'/').'\b/iu';
       return preg_match($s, $str, $out) ? $out[0] : false; }, $arr));

sort($res); print_r($res);
```

[See test at eval.in](https://eval.in/392996) (*anonymous functions with array_map: at least PHP 5.3 is required*)

> Array
>   (
>       `[0] => Adel`
>       `[1] => Adel Sachsen`
>       `[2] => Sachsen`
>   )

The function can be further improved to return arrays, if such as different cases for same words is desired or capturing the offset.

Comment: Thanks! That work's for me. Can you please explain it a little bit more? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan Great that works you :] It matches each item of the `$arr` separately on `$str`. No worries for overlapping matches here.  Using word boundaries and caseless matching. The map function is just to avoid a foreach loop.  `$res` array is set with the returned match or `false`. False elements are filtered and finally is sorted/keys reindexed (which might not be necessary).

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookahead to get your ovelaping matches:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=\b(abituria|absolvia|adel sachsen|adel|sachsen|könig)\b)/ui',
         $string, $matches);

print_r($matches[1]);
Array
(
    [0] => König
    [1] => Sachsen
    [2] => Adel Sachsen
    [3] => Sachsen
)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pT1sI1/2)

---

**Update:** Based on your updated code snippet you can do this:

```
 preg_match_all('/(?=\b(adel sachsen)\b)(?=\b(adel)\b)/ui', $string, $matches); 
 unset($matches[0]);
 print_r($matches);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Adel Sachsen
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Adel
        )
)
```

Comment: But it does not work, when regex-word-order changes: (?=\b(abituria|absolvia|adel|adel sachsen|sachsen|könig)\b) Can you fix this?

Comment: But not in PHP.. i got: Array
(
    [0] => König
    [1] => Sachsen
    [2] => Adel
    [3] => Sachsen
)

Comment: I've updated my question with your improvement, but I still got not the expected result.

Comment: Lookahead helps to match AB and B in AB, but not to match AB and A in AB because both start at the same character

Comment: See my updated on how to use lookaheads to see how it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

As you already noticed, `preg_match_all` continues searching after the end of each last match, so it is not the best tool for your task.

The easy but less performant solution would be to do one `preg_match` for each single search term instead.

If the strings are not much longer than your example I would go for this, optimizing it seems not to be worth it.

If performance is really critical, I would group prefixes of other terms with them, ordering each group by longest term first:

- abituria
- absolvia
- adel sachsen, adel
- sachsen
- könig

Now use the regex with lookahead assertion:

```
preg_match_all('/(?=\b(abituria|absolvia|adel sachsen|adel|sachsen|könig)\b)/ui',
     $string, $matches);
```

If `$string` contains "adel", but not "adel sachsen", it will match correctly. If it contains "adel sachsen", it will only match "adel sachsen", but from the groups that we constructed before, we know that it also matches prefixes of "adel sachsen", i.e. "adel".